# How to use all of these: *args, **kwargs, "*" and "/"

Tags: python, arguments, signature, keyword-argument

I was practicing with different function signatures and wanted to try a function with all of these: positional and key-word arguments, with variable number of those, along with specifying positional- keyword- arguments only.

I got thus far:

```
def fun(a, /, b, *, c=None, **kwargs):
    print(f"{a = }, {b = }, {c = }")
```

where `a` is positional-only argument, `b` can be either positional or keyword, `c` is keyword-only argument, and additional keyword arguments are allowed.

However, when I tried to collect additional positional arguments in `*args`, it resulted in a syntax error. I think all the possible places for `*args` were tested.

Is it impossible to use all, `/`, `*`, `*args` and `*kwargs` at the same time? Or perhaps I missed one possibility?

**EDIT**

On 2023.08.14 an article was published: ["What Are Python Asterisk and Slash Special Parameters For?" (Real Python)](https://realpython.com/python-asterisk-and-slash-special-parameters/)

Comment: You can only have `*` *or* `*args`. Both makes no sense.

Comment: What do you mean by 'optional positional arguments'? An optional argument is formatted with a default, like def f(a=False). A positional argument is a required argument.

Comment: Byron: "optional positional arguments" was a mistake. I meant a variable number of positional arguments. It was corrected.

Answer (score 3):

```
def foo(a, *args, b)
```

Here `a` is positional, `args` soaks up any additional positional arguments, and `b` is a keyword parameter. There is absolutely no point in including `*` here, as its only role is to terminate positional parameters and start keyword parameters. But `*args` already does that.

You can think of `*` as `*args` without `args`, meaning additional positional arguments will not be soaked up into a parameter. Other than that, `*` and `*args` already do the same job. Which makes sense, since they use the same "`*`".